# Div appear on hover of different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I was wondering if it is possible to make #text-1 to appear with an animation of `opacity:0;` to `opacity:1;` when #screamer is hovered over?

I want `#text-1` to appear under `#screamer` in a transition when div b is hovered over, div b is CSS circle (box with border-radius of 50% to width of 60px and height 60px) with a background image. the box color has an opacity of 0.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
/* ABOUT */

#aboutus {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
/* MANAGERS */

#managers-head {
  font-weight: 500;
}
#importantpeople {
  text-align: center;
}
#importantpeopletxt {
  text-align: center;
}
#manager-1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
#manager-2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
#manager-3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#important {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 430px;
}
#screamer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#kinzu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#swezii {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#text-1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 150px;
  float: left;
}
#text-2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 150px;
}
#text-3 {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="importantpeople">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="importantpeople">
      <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="importantpeopletxt">
      <h6 id="manager-1">Screamer</h6>
      <h6 id="manager-2">KINZU</h6>
      <h6 id="manager-3">Swezii</h6>
      <p id="text-1">Just a guy chilling on his computer creating works of art for people</p>
      <p id="text-2">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
      <p id="text-3">I love Web, App and other designing. It is my goal to get rid of bad design in my city.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Easiest way is to just add/remove a class to #screamer when hovering div b using JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it is possible to make #text-1 to appear with an
>   animation of opacity:0; to opacity:1; when #screamer is hovered over?

Since `#screamer` and `#manager-1` aren't siblings or parent-child, you'll need JavaScript for this.

You've tagged jQuery, so here's a quick-and-dirty:

```
$('#screamer').hover(
  function() {
    $('#text-1').animate({opacity: 1});
  },
  function() {
    $('#text-1').animate({opacity: 0});
  }
);
```

**CSS**

```
#text-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('#screamer').hover(
  function() {
    $('#text-1').animate({opacity: 1});
  },
  function() {
    $('#text-1').animate({opacity: 0});
  }
);
```

```css
/* ABOUT */

#aboutus {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
/* MANAGERS */

#managers-head {
  font-weight: 500;
}
#importantpeople {
  text-align: center;
}
#importantpeopletxt {
  text-align: center;
}
#manager-1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
#manager-2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
#manager-3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#important {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 430px;
}
#screamer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x100");
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#kinzu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x100");
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#swezii {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x100");
  background-size: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#text-1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 150px;
  float: left;
}
#text-2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 150px;
}
#text-3 {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#text-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="importantpeople">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="importantpeople">
      <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="importantpeopletxt">
      <h6 id="manager-1">Screamer</h6>
      <h6 id="manager-2">KINZU</h6>
      <h6 id="manager-3">Swezii</h6>
      <p id="text-1">Just a guy chilling on his computer creating works of art for people</p>
      <p id="text-2">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
      <p id="text-3">I love Web, App and other designing. It is my goal to get rid of bad design in my city.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ops I meant show #text-1 on hover of #screamer (facepalm)

Comment: I've updated my answer.  But not real clear on the "div b" part of your question.

Comment: Put the CSS in an external CSS file (or between `<style></style>` tags.)  Put the JavaScript in an external JS file (or between `<script></script>` tags.)  If you're not already using jQuery, you should probably remove the tag, and I'll provide a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Thanks, @humble.rumble, the transition was left over from my first answer, when the problem *was* solvable using CSS only.  I've removed the transition, but your `css` suggestion would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla solution for future viewers. No jQuery required.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/xy551dyo/1/))

#### CSS

```
#text-1 {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var screamer = document.getElementById('screamer');
    screamer.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        var text1 = document.getElementById('text-1');
        text1.style.opacity = '1';
    }, false);
    screamer.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        var text1 = document.getElementById('text-1');
        text1.style.opacity = '0';
    }, false);
})();
```

#### EDIT:

If you would like to be able to hover toggle a section of text for each "manager" you can do something like this. Note I've modified the HTML and CSS quite a bit here so you would have to use the HTML and CSS as well as the Javascript

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/xy551dyo/3/))